# Using Autolayout adjust vertical position from horizontal center if too high

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

In the diagram I need to center align the right view with the left view. If the right view is larger than the left view I need to top align it. Can I do this with constraints (storyboard) or do I need to do something in code to adjust the position (via a constraint) of the right view after the size has been determined? The Right view has multiple UILabels that can grow so I don't know the size until runtime. The container is actually a UITableViewCell.[image]

Centering is easy. The right view resizes and the cell adjusts to that size. The issue is the requirement to top align if its too big.

Comment: try in this way: align to the top constraint of left view and give the half width of left view as negative value to the top align constraint. You can change this value to 0 programmatically when right view is larger that left view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

[image: demo]

You can do it with two constraints.

You want the top of the green view to be greater than or equal to the top of the pink view, **always**. That is, you require that `green.top ≥ pink.top`.

In addition, you want the Y-center of the green view to be equal to the Y-center of the pink view, **when possible**. That is, you prefer that `green.centerY == pink.centerY`, if it doesn't violate the other constraint.

Here's the first constraint, in the storyboard editor:

[image: first constraint]

And here's the second constraint:

[image: second constraint]

Note that I have lowered the second constraint's priority to 800, which means it's not required but it's strongly preferred.

You don't need to write any code to make this work. I did write code in my demo to wire up the slider and the label, but I didn't have to modify those two constraints from code.

Comment: Excellent!  I always struggle with the priorities option.Hence I never touched those!!! Seems I should look into that!!!

Comment: I was just getting to this idea when I came back to here and saw your demo! Thanks.

Comment: When I actually used it in a UITableViewCell combined with using constraints to calculate the height of the cell, everything works but I had to lower the priority of the center to 500. Oddly enough on the simulator it's very jumpy as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the storyboard, align the right view to the left view top.
2. Give the value as

   ```
   topAlignCons.value= +(leftView.height/2)  //in storyboard
   ```

   so that it gets align to the center of left view
3. Create an outlet for the top align constraint in your view controller.
4. When the right view is larger that left view, change the outlet constraint value to 0.

   ```
    topAlignConstraint.constant=@0;
   ```

   Now it will be aligned to the left view top with no negative value.

Comment: I thought of that. Where do I put the code that adjusts the top constraint so that I will know how big the right view is after its been calculated?

Comment: Also width doesn't seem to be an option in the storyboard.

Comment: if u give the height constriant as 20....the topalign constraint for your right view must be 10...and later it must be 0.

Comment: I only see top, center y, baseline(2) and bottom

Comment: u can give height constraint in the IB.

Comment: For a top alignment I only see the items listed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105846/discussion-between-teja-nandamuri-and-ahwulf).